# Embedded Linux: getting two distinct DHCP responses

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded

I'm using these bootargs:

```
setenv bootargs 'console=ttyPS0,115200n8 root=/dev/nfs rootfstype=nfs nfsroot=192.168.0.101:/usr/nfs/xilinx-zynq,port=2049,nolock,proto=tcp rw loglevel=8 tcp ip=dhcp'
```

The most important to note is probably `ip=dhcp`. Looking at the boot log, I'm getting two different IP addresses.

- How could this be?
- Is it possible to cancel the second request?

First IP:

```
[    7.792623] IP-Config: Complete:
[    7.795836]      device=eth0, hwaddr=00:0a:35:00:22:01, ipaddr=192.168.0.102, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=192.168.0.254
[    7.806161]      host=192.168.0.102, domain=, nis-domain=(none)
[    7.812063]      bootserver=0.0.0.0, rootserver=192.168.0.101, rootpath=     nameserver0=192.168.0.254
```

Second IP:

```
INIT: Entering runlevel: 5
Configuring network interfaces... udhcpc (v1.24.1) started
Sending discover...
Sending select for 192.168.0.93...
Lease of 192.168.0.93 obtained, lease time 73202
/etc/udhcpc.d/50default: Adding DNS 192.168.0.254
done.
```

Answer (score 0):

I still do not understand why I'm getting two different IP addresses in both cases, but I have found how to eliminate the second DHCP call:

In **/etc/network/interfaces**, I put the following:

```
# /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)

# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


# Wired or wireless interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```

The key point here is the "manual" setting, which tells the system to not try to activate the interface, because it is already activated.

BTW I have read somewhere that relying on the initial DHCP is not recommended because the lease is never renewed this way, but I'm not sure what are the implications of that.